# generate random choice each time in array with no repeat in android

Tags: android

I'm developing multiple choice question game. It has four integer choices. Options are stored in an array list. I want to display the choices with the elements in the array in random order with no repetition each time. Please give me the solution.

```
int ans[] = new int[] { sum, sum + 1, sum + 2, sum - 1 };

    ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i : number) {
        number.add(ans[i]);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(number);

    but1.setText("" + number.get(0));
    but2.setText("" + number.get(1));
    but3.setText("" + number.get(2));
    but4.setText("" + number.get(3));
```

Comment: Have you tried this code?

Answer (score 2):

**makeRandomArray** returns an random int array between your size input. So if you pass size = 4, it returns an random array from 0 to 3, then handle your problem with random output. Hope this help!

```
 /**
 * Make an int random array with value from 0 to max
 * @param size: size = max + 1
 * @return result: an int array
 */
private int[] makeRandomArray(int size) {
    int result[] = new int[size];
    List<Integer> ascesdingArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ascesdingArray.add(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int randomValue = random(ascesdingArray);
        result[i] = randomValue;
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Get random value in input array
 * @param ascesdingArray
 * @return randomValue: random element from input array
 */
private int random(List<Integer> ascesdingArray) {
    int max = ascesdingArray.size() - 1;
    int randomValue = 0;
    if (max > 0) {
        // get random index and it's value
        int index = new Random().nextInt(max);
        randomValue = ascesdingArray.get(index);
        // remove value got from array so it will not be duplicated
        ascesdingArray.remove(index);
    } else if (max == 0) {
        randomValue = ascesdingArray.get(0);
    }
    return randomValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code will produce an IndexOutOfBoundsException due to you are iterating over an empty list making the result list empty and next your are picking four items from that empty list.

Finally, answering your question for your specific situation the next code will work:

It's a simplified and corrected working version of your code (tested):

```
List<Integer> number = Arrays.asList(sum, sum + 1, sum + 2, sum - 1);

Collections.shuffle(number);  

but1.setText("" + number.get(0));
but2.setText("" + number.get(1));
but3.setText("" + number.get(2));
but4.setText("" + number.get(3));
```

Hope it helps